# How to use jni to wrap a C DLL?

Tags: java, c, dll, java-native-interface

I'm working on a Java/Eclipse project and need to change an obsolete library jar by a C DLL.

To do that I use the command javac and javah, it create the .h files and I write a .c file.

The C file will call the C DLL and I will compile all this jni C project in a new DLL for Java and use loadLibrary with it.

What happened is that the DLL need complex parameters and I don't know how to do it correctly (I new to Java and jni).

This is the .h file used by the the DLL needing to be wrapped.

```
typedef unsigned char  u_char;
typedef unsigned int   u_int;
typedef unsigned short u_short;

typedef void (*pcap_handler)(u_char *, const struct pcap_pkthdr *,
                 const u_char *);

typedef struct _B
{
  char addr[50];
  int port;
} B;

typedef struct _A
{
  B *links;
  int nb_links;
} A;

typedef enum {0, 1, 2} E;

void set_enum(E debug);
void set_name(const char *name);
void message(const char *format,...);
void init_link(B *link);   
A init_links(int nb_links);
void free_links(A *link_set);
int init_capture(int inum, const B links, int defragment, pcap_handler packet_handler);
int init_capture_from_file(const char *input_file_name, const A links, int defragment, pcap_handler packet_handler);
```

And here is the Java file (not finished).

```
public class Hello
{
    static
    {
        try {
            System.loadLibrary("Hello");
        }
        catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {
            System.err.println("Native code library failed to load.\n" + e);
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    class B
    {
      char addr[];
      int port;
    }

    class A
    {
      B []links;
      int nb_links;
    }

    public enum E {ZERO, ONE, TWO};

    public native void set_enum(E debug);
    public native void set_name(final String name);
    public native void message(final String []format);
    public native void init_link(B []link);
    public native A init_links(int nb_links);


    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        Hello hello = new Hello();
        B link1 = hello.new B();
        String str = "50 characters";

        hello.set_name("name");
        hello.set_enum(E.ONE);
        hello.message(new String[] {"first", "second", "third"});
        link1.addr = str.toCharArray();
        link1.port = 42;

        B []link = new B[] {link1};

        hello.init_link(link);
        A link_set = hello.init_links(123);
    }
}
```

My try with the C file is here.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <jni.h>
#include <Hello.h>
#include <Hello_E.h>
#include <Hello_A.h>
#include <Hello_B.h>

typedef struct _B
{
  char addr[50];
  int port;
} B;

typedef struct _A
{
  B *links;
  int nb_links;
} A;

typedef enum {0, 1, 2} E;

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_Hello_set_1enum(JNIEnv *env, jobject object, jobject debug)
{
    jmethodID enumGetValueMethod = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, (*env)->FindClass(env, "Hello$E"), "ordinal", "()I");
    jint value = (*env)->CallIntMethod(env, debug, enumGetValueMethod);
    printf("set_1enum: %d\n", value);

    E enum_debug = value;
    //Call true dll fonction
    //set_debug(E debug);
}


JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_Hello_set_1name(JNIEnv *env, jobject object, jstring name)
{
    const char *str = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, name, 0);
    if (str == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error in set_1name\n");
        return;
    }
    printf("set_1name: %s\n", str);

    //Call true dll fonction
    //set_name(const char *name);

    (*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, name, str);
}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_Hello_message(JNIEnv *env, jobject object, jobjectArray str_array)
{
    int length = (*env)->GetArrayLength(env, str_array);
    const char *format[length];

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        jstring string = (jstring) (*env)->GetObjectArrayElement(env, str_array, i);
        const char *rawString = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, string, 0);

        format[i] = malloc(strlen(rawString) + 1);
        strcpy((char *)format[i],rawString);
        printf("message - format[i]: %s   - raw string: %s\n", format[i], rawString);
        (*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, string, rawString);
        printf("message format[i]: %s   i:%d\n", format[i], i);
    }

    //Call true dll fonction
    // message(const char *format,...);

    // free
     for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        free((char *)format[i]);
    }
}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_Hello_1init_1link(JNIEnv *env, jobject object, jobjectArray jlinks)
{
    int length = (*env)->GetArrayLength(env, jlinks);
    B links[length];

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {

        B link;
        jobject  objectLink = (*env)->GetObjectArrayElement(env, jlinks, i);
        jclass afdxLink = (*env)->FindClass(env, "Hello$B");

        // get the addr char [] and stock it in links[i].addr as char [50]

        jfieldID  fid = (*env)->GetFieldID (env, afdxLink, "port", "I");
        myInt = (*env)->GetIntField (env, objectLink, fid);
        link.port = myInt;

        links[i] = link;
        printf("init_1link[i].port: %d\n", links[i].port);
    }

    //Call true dll fonction
    // init_link(B *link);
}

JNIEXPORT jobject JNICALL Java_Hello_init_1links(JNIEnv *env, jobject object, jint nb_links)
{
    jclass jni_a = (*env)->FindClass(env, "Hello$A");
    jclass jni_b = (*env)->FindClass(env, "Hello$B");
    A link_set;
    link_set.links = NULL;
    link_set.nb_links = nb_links;

    printf("init_1links :%d\n", link_set.nb_links);

    //Call true dll fonction
    // link_set = init_links(nb_links);


    jmethodID constructor;
    jobject link_set_obj;

    if (afdx_link_set == NULL || afdx_link == NULL)
    {
        printf("aio_1init_1links - Couldn't create new jclass from class AFDXLinkSet or AFDXLink\n");
        return (NULL);
    }
    if ((constructor = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, afdx_link_set, "<init>", "()Hello$AFDXLinkSet")) == NULL)
    {
        printf("aio_1init_1links - Couldn't create new jmethodID from class AFDXLinkSet\n");
        return (NULL);
    }
    if ((link_set_obj = (*env)->NewObject(env, afdx_link_set, constructor)) == NULL)
    {
        printf("aio_1init_1links - Couldn't create new jobject from class AFDXLinkSet\n");
        return (NULL);
    }
    return (link_set_obj);
}
```

The first functions (`set_enum`, `set_name`, and `message`) work but will need to make the call to the DLL function later which could be tricky. The last two (init_link and init_links) are harder, I can't find how to get a good character [50] value from the jobjectarray in init_link and for init_links I have trouble with the jobject constructing.

Could you tell me if I'm doing correctly with the create a JNI DLL between the Java and C DLL?

And also some tips about getting params from inner class or creating jni params would be appreciated.

Comment: Consider bridging instead of wrapping. See Dependency Inversion Principle. Write the Java interface that the application demands from the service first. It should be natural, idiomatic Java.

Comment: I am sorry but can you give me more information ? I a little lost with how to use the Dependency Inversion with JNI

Comment: This applies when you are writing a library for the purpose of meeting the needs of an application. (It does not apply when writing a general-purpose library that many applications could use differently.) The application defines what it needs from the library and the library is written to satisfy it. Refer to this [diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle#/media/File:Dependency_inversion.png). It seems like this applies to your situation because you say you are replacing an old library B in an existing application A. Extract an interface from the old one, maybe?